UNIQUE-PATH in P assuming LPATH is in P
We define the following languages:
LPATH = {<G, a, b, k>|G is an undirected graph that contains a simple path of length at least k from a to b}.
UNIQUE-PATH = {<G, a, b>| G is an undirected graph. The longest simple path from a to b in G is unique}.
Assuming LPATH ∈ P, prove that UNIQUE-PATH ∈ P.
Any idea I had resulted in me getting stuck at the part where I needed to differentiate if an edge was needed to the path or not (so I could delete it and see if the path was unique).
I would appreciate any ideas you might have regarding this one.

We discourage "here is my exercise, how do I solve it?" style questions, because they're unlikely to be helpful to others in the future.  We're happy to help you understand the concepts but just solving exercises for you is unlikely to achieve that. You might find this page helpful in improving your question.

Edited the post.

Hint:
this is perhaps not the best argument, but it follows the intuition you mentioned in the question.
Note that, assuming $\text{LPATH} \in \text{P}$, it is easy to find, in polynomial time, a longest simple path $p$ in $G$ ( I leave the details to you).
Then,  it is straight-forward to take it from here and use $p$ to find if there is a different longest simple path in $G$.

Thanks. What I needed was, really, just a little push.

Let $G = (V,E)$ and $n = |V|$. An easy polytime algorithm solving $UNIQUE-PATH$:
for i in range(n, -1, -1):
    if LPATH(G, i):
        for v in V:
            Let G’ be G with v removed from its vertices.
            if LPATH(G’, i):
                Return False
    return True

Proof is simply that the first time the $LPATH(G, i)$ guard passes, the program variable $i$ will be the length of the longest simple path(s). Fix a path $p$, and assume there is another simple path $q$ of the same length. Because $|p|=|q|$ there is at least one vertex $v*$ in $p$ not found in $q$. Thus for the $v*$ iteration of the inner loop, $LPATH(G, i) = LPATH(G', i)$ since removing $v*$ leaves $q$ intact and the program will return False.
The case where the path $p$ was unique is symmetric - there is no such $q$ and $v*$ and upon exiting the inner loop the algorithm returns True.
